# Как оформить ряд со спанами визуально как таблицу?

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, bootstrap, html, css, вёрстка

Bootstrap 2 3 2

Как оформить ряд со спанами визуально как таблицу?

Задача сделать таблицу, и самое простое решение сделать ее, как обычную таблицу. Вот так она выглядит:

[image]

Я хочу, чтобы при маленькой ширине экрана ячейки таблицы выстраивались по вертикали. Делаю это с помощью row-fluid и 4 span3. Получаются дефолтные отступы между спанами. Применяю к ним margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px. Отступов нет, выглядит почти как нужно, но теперь все спаны не по центру, а сдвинуты влево на величину этих маржинов. Как это исправить? Возможно, вы знаете, как сделать по-другому и лучше?

[image]

Comment: Если нужно сделать таблицу - используйте таблицу (c) Ваш кэп

`
<table class="table">
   <tr>
     <td class="span3"></td>
     <td class="span3"></td>
     <td class="span3"></td>
     <td class="span3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
`
Ну а дальше можно настривать стили ячеек уже

Comment: Ах да, это же 2.3.2, в css ещё не забудьте написать:

`
.table tr td.span3 { width: 25%; box-sizing: border-box;}
`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй выводить спаны без переносов строки и пробелов в html-коде между ними